# How to use lmfit model to solve/find the x-value for a given y-value?

Tags: python, lmfit

I know how to use the model to get y-values from given x-values e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import lmfit

mod=lmfit.models.ExponentialModel()

x_test = np.array([100,40,200, 500])
y_test = np.array([0.7, 0.85, 0.5, 0.3])
pars = mod.guess(y_test, x_test)
out = mod.fit(y_test, pars, x=x_test)
x0 = 10
y0 = out.eval(x=x0)
```

But how do I use the model to find the x-value for a given y-value? I have tried:

```
y0 = 10
x0 = out.eval(y=y0)
```

Which does not appear to be what I want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

well, `x` is the independent value.  A function `y(x)` can have multiple `x` values where `y=y0` or at least `y ~= y0`.  Or there may not be any place for which `y=y0`.

You might find it useful to use `np.where()` and/or `np.argmin()` to find the points close to where a function takes some value.  I often use these as helper functions:

```
def index_of(array, value):
    """
    return index of array *at or below* value
    returns 0 if value < min(array)

    >> ix = index_of(array, value)

    Arguments
    ---------
    array  (ndarray-like):  array to find index in
    value  (float): value to find index of

    Returns
    -------
    integer for index in array at or below value
    """
    if value < min(array):
        return 0
    return max(np.where(array<=value)[0])

def index_nearest(array, value):
    """
    return index of array *nearest* to value

    >>> ix = index_nearest(array, value)

    Arguments
    ---------
    array  (ndarray-like):  array to find index in
    value  (float): value to find index of

    Returns
    -------
    integer for index in array nearest value

    """
    return np.abs(array-value).argmin()
```

maybe those will be helpful for you.

Comment: Hmm, I get your point. In this case my exponential function/model will only have one y-value for the x-value too. However, I did get inspired by your index_nearest at the end, by feeding my model a range of x-values (I roughly know what the max x-value can be) and then calling index_nearest on the output y-array. Thank you

Comment: if you know your function y = f(x) is strictly monotonic, then you should also know the converting function x = g(y).   For an exponential function, that would be a logarithm, for example.